# Flutter Images Layout

Tags: flutter

I have several images that I need to display on the screen, the first image is center screen and then 3 at the bottom, the layout of the 3 at the bottom is a single image, and 2 below that.
Using Stack and Align Widgets I have gotten the main image center, but the other images are aligning to the top of the screen and not the bottom even though I am specifying it in the Align Widget.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage("assets/imgs/logo.png"),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5,
                  child: Image(
                    image: const AssetImage("assets/imgs/logo1.png"),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5,
                  ),
                ),
                Flex(
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                      child: const Image(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/imgs/square_logo.jpg"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                      child: const Image(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/imgs/square_logo1.png"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: can you include an image that you are trying to get

Answer (score 0):

Default `Column`'s `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,`,, you can use

```dart
 mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
```